# view on the django server giving 404 error

Tags: django, view, http-status-code-404

I have created 2 function based views, and the second view is raising a `404` error. Below is the code for the `urls` and `views`.

```py
#urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from mysite.views import current, hello


urlpatterns = [
    path("", current, name="time"),
    path("", hello, name="hello"),
]
```

```py
# views.py

import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse


def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world. I Love you alot.Did you not know?")

def current(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

When I run the server I can see the time output but I can't see hello world on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello`. As in I have 2 views defined but I can see one view and not the second one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey! this might come in handy for you... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same path (`''`) for both views in your `urlpatterns`. This is causing a conflict, and only the first view is being matched. To fix this, you should use different paths for each view. Here's an updated version of your `urlpatterns`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from mysite.views import current, hello

urlpatterns = [
    path('', current, name='time'),
    path('hello/', hello, name='hello'), # Updated path for the hello view
]
```

Now, when you visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/`, it will show "Hello world. I Love you a lot. Did you not know?"

Make sure to adjust your URLs accordingly and test both views with their respective paths.